# Trying to hid a variable if the result contains a portion of text

Tags: angular

I have an angular project where in my html I want to use the [display] tag to show or hide a  based on if the controller returns a set of text that contains a particular word.

So the example would be

```
<div [display]="!result.name.contains('jim')">
```

This doesn't work and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `[hidden]` or `*ngIf`?

Comment: Saying "this doesn't work" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A little context would be helpful. Is this a single div on a single page? An element in a list (ngFor)? Is result coming from a service? An @Input? The output from another element on the page?

[display] if I remember is/was an AngularJS convention, and it's been replaced with *ngIf in Angular 2 and later

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```

If this is a single element and not based on a iterated array of elements (via an *ngFor for example), I would suggest putting the logic in the controller and having it return a boolean that you can bind the *ngIf condition to.

For example:

```
<div *ngIf="!isJimInResult()">Content to render when Jim in in result.</div>


isJimInResult():boolean {
    if(result.name.contains('jim')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

If this is in an iterated array, then you'll have to pass the row value of result.name to the function to calculate, but that requires more detail of your project than you've provided here.

A better solution would be to define a variable, and bind to that and then set it whenever result is updated, but again - that requires a little more knowledge about how you're getting that data so to know when to implement the logic that sets/resets that boolean value.